# How to remove hidden utdated scipy file so it won't import with python in VS Code OSX

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scipy

I am currently trying to run a program with Scipy, and I want to use the load_npz module.
Whenever I tried to run it, the compiler would say that that module doesn't exist.
I ran `scipy.__version__` and got 0.13.0b1, which makes sense as to why it couldn't find the module as it doesn't exist in that version, but I am confused as I have 1.5.2 installed in both pip and brew yet it keeps defaulting to the oldest version which is very frustrating.

Does anybody know how to get rid of this version? I have tried uninstalling from pip and brew, along with finding the path of the imported scipy with the outdated version yet it still is causing issues.
I do have a lot of packages installed (numpy, matplotlib, etc.) so could it be a dependency that keeps reinstalling an old version?

Strangely, even if I delete scipy from both brew and pip, it will still show the old version but throw an error on a different local file that also uses scipy saying the module does not exist (which is expected as I deleted it).

Answer (score 0):

write this python to find out the location of the imported scipy

```
import scipy
print(scipy.__file__)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just deleted all my possible scipy locations and then just downloaded Anaconda and I'm using that as my python interpreter.